# Cron Invalid username and/or password, After 4.2.9 to 4.2.20 Joomla Upgrade

Tags: cron-job

Very grateful if anyone can tell me where to start debugging this issue.

I had cron working fine in 4.2.9

I've cleared all, caches, templates, sessions, logged in and out as the cron user who is Super Admin. Key was also restored from backup settings files.

Answer (score 1):

This is all due to Joomla changing its password authentication methods on 2.5.18 and above, to fix (not the nicest fix but it works) you need to edit the following.

administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Joomla.php

CHANGE TO THIS AROUND LINE 445

```
  // now check password
  if (strpos($dbPassword, ':') === FALSE) {
    if ($dbPassword != md5($password)) {
      if (!JUserHelper::verifyPassword($password, $dbPassword, $dbId)) {
        return FALSE;
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    list($hash, $salt) = explode(':', $dbPassword);
    $cryptpass = md5($password . $salt);
    if ($hash != $cryptpass) {
      if (!JUserHelper::verifyPassword($password, $dbPassword, $dbId)) {
        return FALSE;
      }
    }
  }
```